# How to get property of class that is nested in IGrouping collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection

I created a generic method to sort. I took type of list, then lookup of prop name that is equal to sortorder from view. Now I have a case with `IGrouping` collection - for example `List<IGrouping<int, ViewModel>>` and I dont know how to sort by props from `ViewModel` which is nested in `IGrouping`

```
    public static List<IGrouping<int, T>> SortOrder<T>(List<IGrouping<int, T>> list, string sortOrder) where T : new()
    {
        Type listType = AssemblyHelper.GetCollectionType(list);
        if (listType.Name.Contains("IGrouping")) { listType = listType.GenericTypeArguments[1]; }

        foreach (var prop in listType.GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.Name.ToLower() == sortOrder)
            {
                if (AssemblyHelper.GetCollectionType(list).Name.Contains("IGrouping"))
                {
EDIT 2: var test = list.OrderBy(x => x.Select(y => prop.GetValue(y, null))).ToList();

                    return //How to OrderBy ViewModel prop that is equal to sort order
                }
                else
                {
                    return list.OrderBy(x => prop.GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
                }
            }
        }
        return default(List<IGrouping<int, T>>);
    }
```

***EDIT2:***

I added:

```
var test = list.OrderBy(x => x.Select(y => prop.GetValue(y, null))).Skip((pageId - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

but I'm getting error `System.ArgumentException: 'At least one object must implement IComparable.'`

So I added something like this to `ImageObjectModel` model:

```
public int CompareTo(ImageObjectModel that)
{
    if (this.Name == that.Name) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

but I still getting this error.

***EDIT:***

**Controller**

```
public ViewResult List(string sortOrder = "", string filter = "")
{
    List<IGrouping<int, ImageObjectModel>> images = null;
    //the rest of views are using just a list, only for this view purpouse I have to use IGrouping collection
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
    {
        images = Filter.MultipleWhereClause(repositoryImageObject.Images.ToList(), filter);
    }
    else
    {
        images = repositoryImageObject.Images.ToList();
    }
    //some logic not related
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder))
    {
        imvm.Images = Sort.SortOrder(images, sortOrder);
    }
    ImageManagerViewModel imvm = new ImageManagerViewModel(images, pageId, sortOrder, filter, isActive);
}
```

**View**

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("DataFilterSortOrderDropDown", new DataFilter.SortOrderDropDown { Obj = Model.Images, SortOrder = Model.SortOrder })
```

**ViewComponent**

```
    public class DataFilterSortOrderDropDownViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private List<SelectListItem> sortOrderList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        public IViewComponentResult Invoke(DataFilter.SortOrderDropDown vm)
        {
            vm.Error = false;
            if (vm.Obj is ICollection<ProductModel>)
            {
                Type collectionType = AssemblyHelper.GetCollectionType(vm.Obj as ICollection<ProductModel>);
                vm = SortOrder(collectionType, sortOrderList, vm);
            }
            //many else if with `vm.Obj is someViewModel`
            else if (vm.Obj is ICollection<IGrouping<int, ImageObjectModel>>)
            {
                Type collectionType = AssemblyHelper.GetCollectionType(vm.Obj as ICollection<IGrouping<int, ImageObjectModel>>);
                vm = SortOrder(collectionType, sortOrderList, vm);
            }
            else
            {
                vm.Error = true;
                return View(vm);
            }

           vm.List.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Value = "sort", Text = string.Empty });
            return View(vm);
        }

    private DataFilter.SortOrderDropDown SortOrder(Type collectionType, List<SelectListItem> sortOrderList, DataFilter.SortOrderDropDown vm)
    {
        FieldInfo[] fields = AssemblyHelper.GetFields(typeof(Sort));
        if (collectionType.Name.Contains("IGrouping")) { collectionType = collectionType.GenericTypeArguments[1]; }
        foreach (var prop in collectionType.GetProperties())
        {
            //take field from sort class and find it in collection type if there is then create `SelectListItem` for dropdown
        }
        vm.List = sortOrderList;
        return vm;
    }
```

**Sort Class**

```
    public const string Name = "name";
    public const string Price = "price";
    public const string Value = "value";
    public const string CreateDate = "createdate";
    public const string EditDate = "editdate";
    public const string Desc = "_desc";
    //etc

    public static IQueryable<T> SortOrder<T> (IQueryable<T> list, string sortOrder) where T : new()
    {
        Type listType = AssemblyHelper.GetCollectionType(list);
        foreach (var prop in listType.GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.Name.ToLower() == sortOrder && isPaging)
            {
                return list.OrderBy(x => prop.GetValue(x, null));
            }
            else if (prop.Name.ToLower() + Sort.Desc == sortOrder && isPaging)
            {
                return list.OrderByDescending(x => prop.GetValue(x, null))
            }

        }
        return default(IQueryable<T>);
    }
```

I removed a lot of code for the clarity of the code. The idea is, if some class have a some properties (name,price,date etc) then create a drop down for it and sort all collections.

My aim is to rewrite `IQueryable` for `IGrouping`

Comment: Why instead of introducing `SortOrder`, a standard one `OrderBy` cannot be used? Smt like `someGroups.OrderBy(group => group.Max((ViewModel item) => item.SomeProperty))` . I would encourage you try to implement the sorting using `OrderBy`, then that code might be refactored to `SortOrder` easier.

Comment: this is just a slice of bigger logic, it's a universal sorting dropdown that's used on several views where there are different viewmodels. I have to do it in generic way

Comment: Then please show an example of how `SortOrder` is being called, and `ViewModel` class (which is planned to be sorted using `sortOrder` )

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a way to work on the group. the only solution to my problem was - take out the collection from the group then make order, and then re-grouping.

Additionally grouping by id was wrong idea, the correct results weze then when we group after the same prop what order

```
public static List<IGrouping<object, T>> SortOrder<T>(List<IGrouping<object, T>> list, string sortOrder) where T : new()
{
    Type listType = AssemblyHelper.GetCollectionType(list);
    if (listType.Name.Contains("IGrouping"))
    {
        var t = list.SelectMany(x => x);
        Type tType = AssemblyHelper.GetCollectionType(t);
        foreach (var prop in tType.GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.Name.ToLower() == Value)
            {
                if (sortOrder.Contains("_"))
                {
                    sortOrder = Value + sortOrder.Substring(sortOrder.IndexOf("_"));
                }
                else
                {
                    sortOrder = Value;
                }
            }
            if (prop.Name.ToLower() == sortOrder)
            {
                return t.OrderBy(x => prop.GetValue(x, null)).GroupBy(x => prop.GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
            }
            else if (prop.Name.ToLower() + Sort.Desc == sortOrder)
            {
                return t.OrderByDescending(x => prop.GetValue(x, null)).GroupBy(x => prop.GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
    return default(List<IGrouping<object, T>>);
}
```